# Does node-set() have an ancestor node?

Tags: xslt

I feel, this is a basic XSLT question. From how I understand, a node-set is data structure in itself. From a node-set() I cannot navigate to any node that is outside of the set.  i.e I cannot reach the parent, the beginning of the xml nor its siblings. Is this right?

or

Is there a way to get a parent of a node-set()

Code

```
<neighbourhood>
<parent name = "xyz">
<child address=10> a </child>
<child address=10> b </child>
<child address=15> c </child>
</parent>
</neighbourhood>
```

I have a set of child nodes. I need to eliminate nodes with duplicate 'address'.
There can be n number of 'parent' and m number of 'child' and there could be a grandparent node for the 'child'.

The best and the logical way is probably go by each parent and process their children. But, it is an existing code base and this is an oversimplified example. I do not want to break too many things by touching the caller function and other templates.

So, my question was if I could get the 'parent' with the set of 'child' nodes I have

Thanks for all your responses

Comment: Quick question- why do you need to? I've never needed to do this, I'm wondering if maybe there's a better way of doing whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: Yes!! I think so too. I am just not sure what the right approach is probably. I have updated the question with more details. I did find a workaround to solve my problem but that probably is not the best way to do it

Comment: I am afraid your question is no more clearer that before. If your goal is to eliminate duplicates, then - assuming this is about XSLT 1.0 - use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)  for this purpose, or - if your processor supports it  - the EXSLT `set:distinct()` function. In any case, it's not clear what is a "node-set" in this context and what role the ancestor of such set would play in this.

Answer (score 3):

> Does node-set() have an ancestor node?

`node-set()` is a (extension) function -- not a node. A function cannot have ancestor, because it is not a node.

I suppose that by `"node-set()"` in the question, you mean the value that is returned by the `xxx:node-set()` function (where the prefix "xxx" is bound to a vendor-specific namespace). If so, here is the wanted answer:

By definition, the `xxx:node-set()` function returns the **`document-node()`** (also known as `root-node` in XPath 1.0) of a temporary tree, which is obtained by converting the RTF (Result Tree Fragment), passed as the only argument to this function.

A document-node by definition is at the top of the document hierarchy and is the only node in an XML document, that doesn't have a parent.

**Therefore, the node returned by a called `xxx:node-set()` function doesn't have any ancestors**.

> From a node-set() I cannot navigate to any node that is outside of the set. i.e I cannot reach the parent, the beginning of the xml nor its siblings. Is this right?

Yes, without calling another function that returns a node from another document (such as the standard XPath function `id()` or the standard XSLT function `document()`), or referencing a variable/parameter, it is not possible to navigate to a node from another document only by using XPath location steps.

> or
>
> Is there a way to get a parent of a node-set()

No, the node returned by the `xxx:node-set()` function is a document node and a document node doesn't have a parent (or any other ancestor) node.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix up node sets and `node-set()`s.

What do I mean by this?  Well, a node set is a set of nodes.  In normal, unextended XSLT 1.0, this means a selection of nodes from your input document.  If I do this:

```
<!-- a node set -->
<xsl:variable name="my-node-set"
    select="/indoc/level1/level2"/>
```

the variable `$my-node-set` contains a set of `level2` nodes, but those nodes still live in the input document.  If I subsequently do a `for-each` like so:

```
<nodeset-from-indoc>
    <xsl:for-each select="$my-node-set/level3">
         <parent>
             <xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/>
         </parent>
         <grandparent>
             <xsl:value-of select="local-name(../..)"/>
         </grandparent>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </nodeset-from-indoc>
```

I *will* get the names of the parents and grandparents of each node:

```
<nodeset-from-indoc>
    <parent>level2</parent><grandparent>level1</grandparent>
    <parent>level2</parent><grandparent>level1</grandparent>
    <parent>level2</parent><grandparent>level1</grandparent>
</nodeset-from-indoc>
```

If, however, I hard-code nodes into a variable:

```
<!-- a result-tree fragment -->
<xsl:variable name="my-rtf">
    <level2>
        <level3>1</level3>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3>2</level3>
    </level2>
    <level2>
        <level3>3</level3>
    </level2>
</xsl:variable>
```

this is **not** a node set, but a result tree fragment, since they weren't selected from the input document.  The problem with result tree fragments is that you can't use XPath on them.  I can't, for example, do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$my-rtf/level3">
```

This is where the `node-set()` function comes in.  It is an extension to XSLT 1.0, which comes from some extension namespace, depending on your XSLT processor.  Many processors choose to implement this in the namespace defined by EXSLT.

As Dmitre points out, the node-set() function returns a magic document node of a temporary tree, allowing you to use XPath.  **However**, this causes a subtle shift in how the select needs to be done.  Because of the magic document node, I have to include `level2` in my selection:

```
<nodeset-from-rtf>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($my-rtf)/level2/level3">
        <parent>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name(..)"/>
        </parent>
        <grandparent>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name(../..)"/>
        </grandparent>
    </xsl:for-each>
</nodeset-from-rtf>
```

And in this case, the `level3` nodes will have parents, but no grandparents:

```
<nodeset-from-rtf>
    <parent>level2</parent><grandparent/>
    <parent>level2</parent><grandparent/>
    <parent>level2</parent><grandparent/>
</nodeset-from-rtf>
```

Comment: I should have been more specific. I was talking about the node-set() function that works on an RTF node as Dimitre guessed. But, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

A node-set is a set of nodes. Each node in the node-set has ancestors. The node-set itself does not. If $NS is a node-set, you can do `$NS/ancestor::node()`: this will give you all the ancestors of all the nodes in the node-set, with duplicates eliminated.

Comment: "The node-set itself does not" Thanks, Michael, for confirming this.